# What is the advantage of generator in terms of memory in these two examples?

Tags: python, generator

One of the generator advantage is that it uses less memory and consumes fewer resources. That is, we do not produce all the data at once and we do not allocate memory to all of them, and only a one value is generated each time. The state and status and values ​​of the variables are stored, and in fact the code can be stopped and resumed by calling it to continue.

I wrote two codes and I am comparing them, I see that the generator can be written normally and now I do not see any points for the generator. Can anyone tell me what is the advantage of this generator in compare to when it be written normally? One value is generated with each iteration of both of them.

The first code:

```
def gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2
        i += 1
        yield i

g = gen(3)
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

The second one:

```
def func(i):
    i = i ** 2
    i += 1
    return i

for i in range(3):
    print(func(i))
```

I know that the `id` of `g` is constant whereas the `id` of `func(i)` is changing.

Is that what the main generator advantage means?

Comment: Generators use less memory _compared to calculating all the results and storing them in a list_. Your second code is not doing that. Both will use a similar amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

To be specific about the above codes that you have mentioned in the question, there is no difference in terms of memory between the two approaches you have shown, but first one is more preferable because everything you need is inside the same generator function, whereas in the second case, the loop and the function are at two different places, and every time you need to use the second function, you need to use the loop outside which unnecessarily increases the redundancy.

Actually the two functions you have written, the generator one, and the normal function, they are not equivalent.
In the generator, you are returning all the values, i.e. the loop is inside the generator function:

```py
def gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2
        i += 1
        yield i
```

But, in the second case, you are just returning one value, and the loop is outside the function:

```py
def func(i):
    i = i ** 2
    i += 1
    return i
```

In order to make the second function equivalent to the first one, you need to have the loop inside the function:

```py
def func(n):
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2
        i += 1
        return i
```

Now, of course the above function always return a single value for `i=0` if control goes inside the loop, so to fix this, you need to return an entire sequence, which demands you to have  a list or similar data structure that allows you to store multiple values:

```py
def func(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2
        i += 1
        result.append(i)
    return result

for v in func(3):
    print(v)
    
1
2
5
```

Now, you can clearly differentiate the two cases, in the first one, each values are evaluated sequentially and processed later i.e. `printed`, but in the second case, you ended up having the entire result in memory before you can actually process it.

Comment: I wanted to have the same output. I did not want to compare a very similar code. My question is not about how to write code, but about the advantage of a Generator object  in terms of memory at above codes.

Comment: Thanks for updating. But when we want to use generator outside of generator function, we use loop again in similar to second code. Of course we can use next(g)  in generator, But most of the time in our codes, we want to iterate in generator with a loop structure outsid of it.

Comment: @au.tumn, yeah you are also right, that is why there is term *more preferable*. I'm not saying it should be done that way, I'm just saying it is more preferable. And if that is your question, like which one to use over another among the two approaches you have mentioned in the question,  then the question becomes **opinion based** and we need to close the question.

Comment: yeah. using generator is common.There is a difference yet. generator has constant id in memory but the id of func(i) is changing in any iteration. Thanks for your good answers

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is when you have a large dataset. It is basically the idea of `lazy loading` which means that a data is not called unless it is required. This saves your resources because typically in a list, the entire thing is loaded at once which might take up a lot of primary memory if the data is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the first code is with respect to something you did not show. What is meant that generating and consuming one value at a time takes less memory than first generating all values, collecting them in a list, and then consuming them from the list.

The second code with which to compare the first code should have been:

```
def gen2(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        i = i ** 2
        i += 1
        result.append(i)
    return result

g = gen2(3)
for i in g:
    print(i)
```

Note how the result of `gen2` can be used exactly like the result of `gen` from your first example, but `gen2` uses more memory if `n` is getting larger, whereas `gen` uses the same amount of memory no matter how large `n` is.